# INNER JOIN with limited rows from second table

Tags: sqlite

I have two tables: [TEXT], [CATEGORY]
where each text item has one category
the following sql statement retrieve text items that have "art" category

```
SELECT * from [TEXT], [CATEGORY] WHERE [CATEGORY].[id]=[TEXT].[CATEGORY_id] AND
[CATEGORY].[name] IN ("Art") LIMIT 10
```

what I want to do is do retrieve 10 text items from each category.

10 from Art, 10 from Philosophy, 10 from Science .....

Comment: Why are you using SQL Server delimiters in a question tagged MySQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you really do mean MySQL, the fastest solution involves variables:

```
select t.*
from (SELECT *,
             @rn := if(@cname = c.name, @rn + 1, 1) as rn
             @cname := c.name
      from `TEXT` t join
           CATEGORY c
           on c.id = t.CATEGORY_id cross join
           (select @cname := '', @rn := 0) const
      order by c.name
    ) t
where rn <= 10;
```

I do not like this solution particularly, because MySQL does not guarantee that the assignment to `@rn` occurs before the assignment to `@cname`.  However, it does work in practice.

EDIT:

The above works in MySQL.  In SQLite, you need to do the count using a query:

```
select t.*
from (SELECT *,
             (select count(*) from Text t2 where t2.Category_id = t.Category_Id and t2.id <= t.id
             ) as seqnum
      from TEXT t join
           CATEGORY c
           on c.id = t.CATEGORY_id 
    ) t
where seqnum <= 10;
```

This is actually standard SQL, but generally performance is not so good, so other alternative are preferred.

Note:  this assumes there is some column in `Text` that identifies each row.  I called it `id`.

Comment: wouldn't a sub-query be needed for ` select * from category order by c.name` to make sure the rows are retrieved in a deterministic manner or am I wrong in understanding that the ORDER BY is applied at the last ?

Comment: my database is actually an sqlite database and I get an 
unrecognized token ":" 
error when I run the sql statement above

Comment: @user1850632 . . . You should tag your questions with the correct database.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    CATEGORY.NAME,
    @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank,
    TEXT.NAME    
FROM TEXT 
JOIN ( select NAME.ID, @curRank := 0 from CATEGORY) CATEGORY
       ON CATEGORY.ID = TEXT.ID
) CATEGORY
  ON CATEGORY.ID = TEXT.ID
WHERE rank <= 10
ORDER BY 
    CATEGORY.NAME,
    rank
```

Comment: This would probably throw an error saying that column CATEGORY.ID not found !!

Comment: @PieterGeerkens . . . This is incorrect syntax in every database that I know of, which is probably why it is getting downvotes.

Comment: OK - Correlated sub-queries not accepted in FROM clause. Give me a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT * FROM [CATEGORY] 
    JOIN (SELECT [TEXT].[CATEGORY_id], 
    IF( @previous = [TEXT].[CATEGORY_id],
          @temp := @temp + 1, @temp := 1) cnt, 
          @previous := [TEXT].[CATEGORY_id] 
    FROM  [TEXT] ORDER BY [TEXT].[CATEGORY_id] ) t 
    WHERE [CATEGORY].[id]= t.[CATEGORY_id] AND
    [CATEGORY].[NAME] IN ("Art") and cnt <= 10
```